# Animation Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, animation, jsfiddle

I've come up with this little animation that uses images in an array, but it's sloppy. What I'd really like is to modularize it so that I can use **multiple instances of the same function to animate different arrays depending on which key is pressed**. Also, I'd like to get it so that the **animation stops when the key is released**, if possible. I realize that calling all of those variables globally is a big no-no, but I have no idea how to make it work otherwise! Last but not least, I'd like to figure out how to get that **last bit of inline script over to the external file** and have it still work correctly. Any help would be much appreciated! But please note, I'm a novice with JavaScript, so **please try to be as specific/detailed as possible** so I can learn from your wisdom! Thank you!

I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghQwF/2/).

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<span id="jajo"><img id="my_img" src="jajo.png" /></span>
<script>element = document.getElementById("jajo"); </script>
</div><!--wrapper-->
```

JavaScript:

```
var i = 0;
var element;
var waveArray = ["wave0.png","wave1.png","wave2.png","wave3.png","wave4.png","wave5.png"];
var jumpArray = ["jump0.png","jump1.png","jump2.png","jump3.png","jump4.png","jump5.png"];
var foodArray = ["food0.png","food1.png","food2.png","food3.png","food4.png","food5.png"];

document.onkeydown = function(event) {
var keyPress = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);

if(keyPress == "W") { // if "w" is pressed, display wave animation
    increment ();

    document.onkeyup = function(event) { // if "w" is released, display default image
        document.getElementById("jajo").innerHTML= "<img alt='Jajo' src='jajo.png'>";
    }
} else if(keyPress == "A") { // if "a" is pressed, display jump animation
} else if(keyPress == "S") { // if "s" is pressed, display food animation
}
}

function increment (){
i++;
if(i > (waveArray.length - 1)){
    i = 0;
}
setTimeout(animation,1000/30);
}


function animation() {
var img = '<img src="' + waveArray[i] + '" alt="Jajo" />';
element.innerHTML = img;
setTimeout(increment, 2000/30);
}
```

Comment: Never use `setTimeout`/`setInterval` with strings, it's like using evil `eval`! Use `setTimeout(increment, 2000/30);` instead.

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work. Fixed in http://jsfiddle.net/ghQwF/2/

Comment: Gah, thank you! I'll update to that link in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/ghQwF/4/

## Module

```
var animation = (function() {
    var delay = 1000 / 30;
    var map = {}, active = [], timer;
    function animate() {
        for(var i=0, l=active.length; i<l; ++i) {
            var data = map[active[i]];
            ++data.index;
            data.index %= data.array.length;
            data.image.src = data.array[data.index];
        }
        timer = setTimeout(animate, delay);
    }
    function begin(e) {
        var key = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode),
            data = map[key];
        if(!data) return;
        if(!active.length) timer = setTimeout(animate, delay);
        if(!~active.indexOf(key)) active.push(key);
    }
    function end(e) {
        var key = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode),
            data = map[key];
        if(!data) return;
        data.image.src = data.default;
        var index = active.indexOf(key);
        if(!~index) return;        
        active.splice(index, 1);
        if(!active.length) clearTimeout(timer);
    }
    return {
        add: function(data) {
            data.index = data.index || 0;
            data.image = data.image || data.target.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
            data.default = data.default || data.image.src;
            map[data.key] = data;
        },
        remove: function(key) {
            delete map[key];
        },
        enable: function() {
            document.addEventListener('keydown', begin, false);
            document.addEventListener('keyup', end, false);
        },
        disable: function() {
            document.removeEventListener('keydown', begin, false);
            document.removeEventListener('keyup', end, false);
            clearTimeout(timer);
            active = [];
        }
    };
})();
```

## Example

```
animation.enable();
animation.add({
    key: 'W',
    target: document.getElementById('jajo'),
    array: [
        "http://static.spoonful.com/sites/default/files/styles/square_128x128/public/crafts/fingerprint-flowers-spring-craft-photo-420x420-aformaro-01.jpg",
        "http://static.spoonful.com/sites/default/files/styles/square_128x128/public/crafts/paper-flowers-spring-craft-photo-420x420-aformaro-11.jpg",
        "http://static.spoonful.com/sites/default/files/styles/square_128x128/public/crafts/tissue-paper-flowers-kaboose-craft-photo-350-fs-IMG_8971_rdax_65.jpg"
    ]
});
animation.add({ /* ... */ });
```

## Methods

### add

Adds a new animation, with parameters:

- `key`: key to activate animation
- `target`: wrapper of the image (optional if `image` is specified)
- `image`: image to animate (optional, defaults to first image in `target`)
- `default`: default url of the image (optional, defaults to original url)
- `index`: initial position in `array` (optional, defaults to `0`)
- `array`: array of images

### remove

Removes the animation related with `key` specified.

### disable

Disables animations (typing keys would have no effect), and stops current ones.

### enable

Enable animations (typing keys can start animations).